# Music during sefirah and "exemptions"

Tags: music, sefirat-ha-omer

There's a common custom that people do not listen to music during 33 days of the Omer. There are also two customs as to when these days begin:

1. From the 2nd day of Pesach until Lag Ba'omer

or

2. From the 1st of Iyar until the 2nd of Sivan.

I have heard and read that a person observing timeframe 1 may attend a wedding that has music and hosted by someone observing timespan 2 and vice versa. I gather that is an exception to the rule.

However, I have noticed that during Hol Hamo'ed Pesach many places have musical events especially at hotels. Is it that n one attending these hotels are observing timeframe 1, or is Hol Hamo'ed an "exception" for them, too?

Then, Yom Ha'atzma'ut also seems to be an exception as many people observing both timespans seem to be listening to music.

So, I'm trying to gain some clarity on the "no music" rule. It seems that the only commonality for both groups not to hear music is 1 Iyar - 18 Iyar )Lag Ba'omer). Except from Yom Ha'atzma'ut.

It also seems, based on the above, that those observing timespan 1 are getting more "exemptions" (all of Hol Hamo'ed) than those in timespan 2. Regardless, it doesn't seem that anyone is observing the no music ban for a full 33 days.

Are all these days considered "exemptions", or have people become lax on the no music rule, or what?